# Word 2007 new document opens in header editor (error)?

Tags: microsoft-office, microsoft-word-2007, microsoft-office-2007

When I open new document in word 2007 (using File >> New) , new document opens in Header !!!
and I have to exit from it till I can write some notes !
I didn't have this problem and it occurred some days ago.

[image]

Could you please guide me how I can fix it

Answer (score 2):

What you're experiencing is that you've removed the whitespace between the toolbar on top of the page and the page itself.

You can fix it back if you rest the mouse pointer over the gray area above the page (b/w the toolbar and the page) and then double click when you see **Double-click to show white space**.

You can also do this to make a button appear on the quick access toolbar right of the Office button for a faster access:

> ‪  1. ‬Click the **Microsoft Office Button**, and then click **Word
>   Options** on the bottom.
>
> ‪  2.‬ In the left pane, click **Customize**.
>
> ‪  3.‬ In the **Choose commands from list**, click **All Commands**.
>
> ‪  4.‬ Click **White Space Between Pages**, click **Add**, and then
>   click OK. The White Space Between Pages option will appear on the
>   Quick Access Toolbar.

---

**Source:**

- [Microsoft KB297564](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/297564)

Comment: When I `removed the whitespace between the toolbar on top of the page and the page itself.` nothing happen :( . Also, I've done what you said. but nothing changed

Comment: @Mohammad I'm very sure that the problem is what I described; [this picture](http://i.imgur.com/JsOVq.png) tells you the same thing. But if I'm wrong, does it have something to do with these 2 buttons (blue circle) on [your picture](http://i.imgur.com/MNOWP.jpg).

Please unclick the left button and see what happens.